# client side cookies in javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

Long time user first time poster. This site has given me many of answers when books failed me. To my question.

I am attempting to create a shopping cart. For each time a subit/add button is clicked I want to create a new cookie. I thought I was/could accomplish that with this code;

```
var cookieName = document.cookie;
var splitCookieName;
splitCookieName = cookieName.split(";");
for( var i =0; i <= splitCookieName.length; i++)
{
    var cartItemNumber;
    if (splitCookieName[i].slice(0,8) == "cartItem")
    { 
        cartItemNumber = parseInt(splitCookieName[i].slice(8));

        alert(cartItemNumber);
        itemCount = cartItemNumber + 1;
        alert(itemCount);
    } 
}
var newItem = "cartItem" + itemCount;
setCookie(newItem, "", expiryDate);
```

However, every time I run it it only alerts me 1, for the cartitemnumber, and 2, for the item count. So I suppose my question is why does it keep resetting cookies one and two? I thought I read something saying that it is because it is not on a server so it acts differently. Is this true? Or is there an error in my code I am not see.

item count has an initial value of 1.

I am also having an issue of getting the last alert in this code. google chrome straight up doesnt even like it and won't run it, has an issue with allSelects[i].id and doesnt like the options part for some reason. However when I run in firefox it doesnt alert me the last line. But, if I put that line in the for loop it runs it fine just over and over. the code is here.

```
setCookie(newItem, "", expiryDate);

productType = document.getElementById("product");
priceType = document.getElementById("price");

setField(newItem, productType.id, productType.value, expiryDate);
setField(newItem, priceType.id, priceType.value, expiryDate);


allSelects = new Array;
allSelects = document.getElementsByTagName("select");

for(var i = 0; i <= allSelects.length; i++)
{
    setField(newItem, allSelects[i].id, allSelects[i].options[allSelects[i].selectedIndex].text, expiryDate);
}
alert(getField(newItem, "quantity") + " " + getField(newItem, "product") + " added to your shopping cart.");}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Solved my own issue. I A)forgot to add a space after the split(";") and B) I was doing a <= for loop, needed to be just <.

Comment: Though my last alert still doesn't want to work.